# GetAll Netsuite Taxcode (SalesTaxItem) (Advance)

Tags: netsuite

Since Tax Code (SalesTaxItem) don't have a search interface, so that I use getAll function.
But with some users, I receive error message "That record does not exist." although [totalRecords] = 67.

My first question : So how can I avoid this error ?

This is structure of GetAllResponse Object

```
(
    [getAllResult] => GetAllResult Object
        (
            [status] => Status Object
                (
                    [statusDetail] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => StatusDetail Object
                                (
                                    [code] => RCRD_DSNT_EXIST
                                    [message] => That record does not exist.
                                    [type] => ERROR
                                )

                        )

                    [isSuccess] => 
                )

            [totalRecords] => 67
            [recordList] => 
        )

)
```

My second question: On success, I receive SalesTaxItem list.   But don't have subsidiary list.   How can I get subsidiary list of each SalesTaxItem ?

```
[getAllResult] => GetAllResult Object
        (
            [status] => Status Object
                (
                    [statusDetail] => 
                    [isSuccess] => 1
                )

            [totalRecords] => 68
            [recordList] => RecordList Object
                (
                    [record] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => SalesTaxItem Object
                                (
                                    [itemId] => tax company 15
                                    [displayName] => 
                                    [description] => 
                                    [rate] => 1.00%
                                    [taxType] => RecordRef Object
                                        (
                                            [internalId] => -75
                                            [externalId] => 
                                            [type] => 
                                            [name] => Other 25 Sales Tax
                                        )

                                    [taxAgency] => RecordRef Object
                                        (
                                            [internalId] => 1285
                                            [externalId] => 
                                            [type] => 
                                            [name] => Store Tax Agency
                                        )

                                    [purchaseAccount] => 
                                    [saleAccount] => 
                                    [isInactive] => 
                                    [effectiveFrom] => 
                                    [validUntil] => 
                                    [eccode] => 
                                    [reverseCharge] => 
                                    [parent] => 
                                    [exempt] => 
                                    [isDefault] => 
                                    [excludeFromTaxReports] => 
                                    [available] => 
                                    [export] => 
                                    [taxAccount] => RecordRef Object
                                        (
                                            [internalId] => 375
                                            [externalId] => 
                                            [type] => 
                                            [name] => Sales Taxes Payable
                                        )

                                    [county] => 
                                    [city] => 
                                    [state] => 
                                    [zip] => 
                                    [nexusCountry] => 
                                    [internalId] => 955
                                    [externalId] => 
                                    [nullFieldList] => 
                                )
```

Thank you very much.
Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems resolved.
First question :Because data on NetSuite have errors. I removed some invalid records on NetSuite.
Second question: Before I used PHP Toolkit v2013_1_0, when use new Toolkit v2013_2_0, result has SubsidiaryList.
Thank you very much.